# PHP string to XML exclusive C14N

Tags: php, xml, web-services, security, soap

I have an xml document (soap message) , wish i need to sign a part of it (the body). the Algorithm in the server require a sha256 of the body in the exclusive C14n format.

The problem that i hadn't built the document using the DOMDocument, I am just using strings and curl to send, so i can't use the ->C14N(true) method.

any alternatives?

PS: i tried to hash the raw string in sha256, but it doesn't give the same output as a hashed exclusive c14n canocalized string.

example of body :

```
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-samplebody">
<node1 data="x"/>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: Yeah, it need the namespace in the body, wish will modify the hash if i added it.

Comment: Actually, no it has the same fingerprint

Comment: Like everything else in XML this is overly complex and poorly defined. [This Guy's lib seems to cover it](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs), so I'd say either use that or try to pull enough information out of it to sign it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to [Paul Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3942918/paul-crovella) i had to retest the loadXML and C14N() and the result is awsome, it has the same fingerprint. so in order to calculate the hash of the body via XML exclusive C14N, do this :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($string_to_be_signed);
echo base64_encode(sha1($doc->C14N(true)));
```